# How to add thousands of local releases to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a folder containing a few thousand code releases, each release in its own subfolder.  However, I need to start using GitHub but I want my entire collection of code releases to be added to GitHub under the releases section.  What is the easiest way of doing this?

Obviously, I cannot import from an existing repository because I don't have one - it's just a few thousand folders on my computer.

I can't manually commit and tag every release because there are too many.

I know that if I wanted to delete many releases from GitHub in one go, I could just checkout the entire repository, delete the release folders from the Tags folder and then commit the changes.

Is it possible to use a similar technique to add many releases too?  I did try copying a few release folders on my computer to the Tags folder on GitHub but when I commit, GitHub complains that the release folders are out of date and wouldn't accept them.

So I have thousands of release folders on my computer.  How can I upload all these to my repository on GitHub without using import and without manually committing each one individually?  I just want them all to be available in the Releases/Tags categories on GitHub but there are too many to manually commit each one.

Comment: For this sort of thing you would generally create a repository locally: copy files from one release, add them to the repository, tag it, then proceed to do the same thing with the next release, and so for all your releases folders. When you're done, push everything to github.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'copy files from one release, add them to the repository'?  What do you mean by copy, where do I copy the files to and do you mean regular file copy or using Git commands?  And how do I add those files?  I'm fairly new to Git.

Comment: This sounds like an ideal job to write a script for. You could probably use the `git fast-import` feature to quickly convert your folders into a git repo with history. Or simply script out the Git commit logic yourself. Then use a bit of scripting to create the tags based on the folder names. You can use `gh release create` from the github cli project (https://cli.github.com/) to create the releases after pushing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have a folder of releases that looks something like this:

```
myproject-1.0/
myproject-1.1/
myproject-2.0/
```

and so forth. You'd like to import these into a git repository.  We start by creating an empty git repository:

```
git init myproject
```

This will create a directory named `myproject` containing an empty git repository. Change directory to that directory:

```
cd myproject
```

Now, to import your releases, we need to loop over your releases in order, and for each release perform the following actions.

1. Copy all the files from the release into the repository:

   ```
   cp -a ../${release}/* .
   ```
2. Add the files to the repository:

   ```
   git add .
   ```
3. Commit the files:

   ```
   git commit -m "imported release $release"
   ```
4. (Optionally) tag the commit:

   ```
   git tag $release
   ```

   Or to have the tag turned into a GitHub release, created an annotated tag:

   ```
   git tag -a -m "imported $release" $release
   ```

Between each iteration of the above, you'd want to delete all the files in the repository before copying in the next release.

---

To prototype this, I grabbed all the releases of the GNU `hello` project and dropped them into a directory; that means I started with this:

```
$ ls
hello-1.3    hello-2.1.1  hello-2.4  hello-2.7
hello-2.1.0  hello-2.2    hello-2.5  hello-2.8
hello-2.10   hello-2.3    hello-2.6  hello-2.9
```

I wrote the following script to perform the import:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d hello-repo ]; then
    git init hello-repo
fi

# change directory into the repository
cd hello-repo

# iterate over the releases in version order
ls -d ../hello-[0-9]* | sort --version-sort -t- -k2,2 |
while read path; do
  release="${path##*/}"
  echo "importing release: $release"

  rm -rf *
  cp -a $path/* .
  git add .
  git commit -m "imported release $release"
  git tag -a -m "imported $release" "$release"
done
```

Note that I'm using `sort --version-sort ...` to ensure I get the directories listed in the correct order; without that, the lexical sorting of those directories would place `hello-2.10` immediately after `hello-2.1.0`.

I have created a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/larsks/hello-import-example) with the results of running that script so you can see what you end up with.

Because I created annoted tags (`git tag -a ...`), each tag was automatically converted into a GitHub release (see [here](https://github.com/larsks/hello-import-example/releases)).